# SETUID not executing the script as owner when executed via PHP script

Tags: linux, permissions, php, setuid

I have a sh file (with setuid) that I want specific web users to be able to execute from an endpoint:

```
-rwsr-xr-x   1 root root       59 Sep 11 09:47 restart-workers.sh
```

The content of this file is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/supervisorctl restart laravel-worker:*
```

When I invoke this:

```
exec('/var/www/html/restart-workers.sh', $stdout, $status);
```

I always get a permission denied error which I expect as PHP-FPM and Nginx are both running as the `www-data` user, however, I am trying to add the SETUID to the script so when the file is executed, the owner of the file is used to execute the script. Am I invoking this wrong? The `sudo` package is not installed.

> error: <class 'PermissionError'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 557

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/194166 tl;dr: it is a security feature.

Comment: Thanks @Vilinkameni - well this makes it difficult lol permissions are a nightmare

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

Comment: Rather than trying to get a "setuid interpreter script" to work (you probably can't, because it's a well known security no-no), read `man sudo sudoers`.

Comment: You should exec across SSH session, from web interface ther user must provide SSH auth params.